# how to fix 'captcha validation is required' error in c#

Tags: javascript, c#

After checking the i'm not a robot checkbox on validation, there's a java script alert "localhost:12345 says null" then when i click "OK" on the alert then go to click the submit button, still says "Captcha validation is required" even after i validated.

This is for my contact us page, validation won't work even after i got new keys which initially i thought were the problem.
C#

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        classes.Common xCommon = new classes.Common();
        classes.Email xEmail = new classes.Email();

        protected static string ReCaptcha_Key = "6LczL3QUAAAAAGnY8hnA-hgRjHV0q---------";
        protected static string ReCaptcha_Secret = "6LczL3QUAAAAADWlVe0IKVERdq----------";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btn_Contact_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xEmail.ContactUs_Email(txt_Contact_Name.Text, txt_Contact_Email.Text, txt_Contact_No.Text, ddl_Branch.SelectedItem.ToString(), ddl_Division.SelectedValue,ddl_Type.SelectedValue,txt_Contact_Message.Text, ddl_Branch.SelectedValue);

            ltr_MessageReturn.Text = xCommon.Return_Message("contactus", "");
            btn_Contact_Submit.Visible = false;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string VerifyCaptcha(string response)
        {
            string url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + ReCaptcha_Secret + "&response=" + response;
            return (new WebClient()).DownloadString(url);
        }
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
 var onloadCallback = function () {
    grecaptcha.render('dvCaptcha', {
        'sitekey': '<%=ReCaptcha_Key %>',
        'callback': function (response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "default.aspx/VerifyCaptcha",
                data: "{response: '" + response + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var captchaResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(r.d);
                    if (captchaResponse.success) {
                        $("[id*=txtCaptcha]").val(captchaResponse.success);
                        $("[id*=rfvCaptcha]").hide();
                    } else {
                        $("[id*=txtCaptcha]").val("");
                        $("[id*=rfvCaptcha]").show();
                        var error = captchaResponse["error-codes"][0];
                        $("[id*=rfvCaptcha]").html("RECaptcha error. " + error);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
 </script>
```

I expect the validation to pass after a user has selected all the required images to pass validation, and then submitted. but the output still says validation required.

Comment: `there's a java script alert` must be from code you haven't shown as there is no alert in the code you have shown ... possibly a problem on the server side though

Comment: @JaromandaX, oh now i see where its coming from but even after i remove it i still get the same error without the alert now.

Comment: as I said, probably a server side issue?

Comment: @JaromandaX can you please take a look, i editted the code.

Comment: is that the code that handles the POST to `default.aspx/VerifyCaptcha` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes.

Comment: when you debug your code, is `response` in `VerifyCaptcha(string response)` correct?

Comment: @JaromandaX  Yes it is

Comment: what's the value of `r` in `success: function (r) {`